# How to close mongo db idle connections in lumen using jessengers?

Tags: regex, laravel, mongodb, lumen

I am using jessenger package for mongo db connection in lumen.

Issue I am facing is that each api open up a new mongo db connection. which turns out to be bulk of idle db connections of servers resulting wastage of resources and slowness of server.

Server is using `php-fpm` . I have tried solution for `pm=ondemand` with `timeout` of 10 senconds. It worked quite good but failed the stress testing badly because application is largescale.

I am looking for a recommended solution which anyone has already tested to get the idle mongo db connections closed in mongo db.

Comment: This probably would have got better answers on [dba.se] or [sf]; it's not about software development.

Comment: why open a connection on each call ? that for sure kills the server. have you tried with a preset of connections aka Connection pool ?

Comment: Doesn't Laravel close database connections at the end of the request? Are the connections remaining hanging? If yes, maybe that's the case for filing a bug to jessenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the db connection string use the following flag to resolve the issue:

```
disableClientPersistence
```

See
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

> If true, this Manager will use a new libmongoc client, which will not be persisted or shared with other Manager objects. When this Manager object is freed, its client will be destroyed and any connections will be closed. Defaults to false.
>
> Note: Disabling client persistence is not generally recommended.

Comment: This turned out good solution so far. Testing it on different environments. will keep it posted. accepting the solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`maxIdleTimeMS`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) in connection

```
'mongodb' => [
    'options' => [
        'connectTimeoutMS' => 30000, // Connection timeout (in milliseconds)
        'maxIdleTimeMS' => 60000, // Mximum idle time (in milliseconds)
    ],
],
```

Comment: timeout setting was not feasible for the application due to the current scope as some time connection is required for longer timeframe.

Comment: Try manually closing the connection then