# disableClientPersistence => true for mongodb driver in connection string uses a high CPU. How to fix cpu utilization?

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, cpu-usage, aws-application-load-balancer

Following is my connection string in lumen api using jensenger/mongodb.

```
 $config::set("database.connections.mongodb", [                                  
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => [env('MONGODB_CLUSTER_SERVER01'), 
                        env('MONGODB_CLUSTER_SERVER02'), 
                     env('MONGODB_CLUSTER_SERVER03')],
            'database' => $this->dbname,
            'username' => env('MONGODB_CLUSTER_USERNAME'),
        'driver_options' => ["disableClientPersistence" => true],
            'password' => env('MONGODB_CLUSTER_PW'),
            'options' => [
                'database' =>  $this->dbname,
                'r' => 'majority',
                'replicaSet' => 'sdfs',
                'readPreference' => 'secondaryPreferred',
                'authSource' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'),
            ]
        ]);
```

[My old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564723/how-to-close-mongo-db-idle-connections-in-lumen-using-jessengers) explains that I started using
**disableClientPersistence** flag in the connection string and cpu utilization reaches 100% while without this flag CPU utilization is between 15-20%. I am using cx5 large instances.

Can any one guide me if there is any way to resolve these excessive cpu utilizations?

**Notes**

1. My server is always under traffic 8k-60k
2. I am using apache with php-fpm.
3. current php-fpm tweaks are

```
pm.max_children = 50  
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s 
pm.min_spare_servers = 5 
pm.max_spare_servers = 10  
pm.start_servers = 5
```

Comment: You have traffic `8k-60k` monthly or daily?

Comment: continously. server has minimum of 8500 or above ranging up to 60k requests any time. server is continuously under load. @Hassaan

Comment: Can you share server specification ?

Comment: cx5 large instances.